# В PyQt5 time.sleep срабатывает не тогда когда нужно

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5, время

В программе на `python3` с `PyQt5` я делаю такую штуку: в `Qt Designer` у меня есть `textBrowser`, `lineEdit` и кнопка `send`.

При нажатии кнопки, текст из `lineEdit` добавляется в `textBrowser`, после чего по идее должен сработать `time.sleep(1)`. По прошествии времени, которого `textBrowser` должен вывести "окей", но `time.sleep` работает не так как надо, при нажатии кнопки он ждет 1 секунду, `textBrowser` выводит мое сообщение и сразу же выводит "окей", то есть он ждет секунду не после того как сообщение из `lineEdit` уже добавилось в `textBrowser`, а перед всем действием после нажатия кнопки. У меня linux и python 3.6.9.

Хотелось бы выяснить причину проблемы и как ее исправить, заранее благодарю.

Вот код:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import time
from test import Ui_MainWindow

class myapp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myapp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.send.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
    def btnClicked(self):
        lineEditText = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        self.ui.textBrowser.append(lineEditText)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ui.textBrowser.append("окей")

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = myapp()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

**test.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(351, 328)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.send = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.send.setObjectName("send")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.send, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 351, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.send.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "send"))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, в следующих вопросах публикуйте все модули  - ваш пример должен быть воспроизводимым !

Comment: @S.Nick также он должен быть минимальным. Простыню никто не читает.

Comment: @eri для меня важно, чтобы код запускался,  ну и да, чем кода меньше - тем лучше, ошибок меньше :)

Comment: Пока минимальный пример напишешь - все уж решишь и отрефакторишь))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time.sleep` блокирует интерфейс программы, в том числе отрисовку (да оно весь поток блокирует).

Используйте `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot` чтоб вызвать функцию через определенное время.

```
def btnClicked(self):
    lineEditText = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
    self.ui.textBrowser.append(lineEditText)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(
        1000,
        functools.partial(self.ui.textBrowser.append, "окей")
    )
```

Comment: Это правильный и полезный ответ и не может быть с минусом ! От меня вам `+`

Comment: первые 2 строчки написал с мобильного, может этот ответ кому-то показался слишком коротким.